# How to get Gridview Cell values into corresponding textbox values on another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

This is a simple question but I have a gridview with Boundfields for ID, Name, Salary. I have a Item template field that will bring the user to another page with textboxes. I want it so that when the user clicks the hyperlink to update, they are led to a page with textboxes that are preset to the values from the specific row in the gridview so that the user can edit and update.

```
        protected void lnkEditUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEmployee.Rows)
        {
            Employee newe = new Employee();
            newe.ID = int.Parse(((BoundField)row.FindControl("txtID")).Text);
            newe.Name = ((BoundField)row.FindControl("lblName")).Text;
            newe.Salary = ((BoundField)row.FindControl("Salary")).Text;

            Session["Update"] = newEmployee;
        }
        Response.Redirect("~/EditUpdateEmployee.aspx");
    }
```

.aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="ID" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
     DataSourceID="EmployeeSQL" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditUpdate" runat="server" Text="Edit/Update" OnClick="lnkEditUpdate_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="NetID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" SortExpression="Salary" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: If you use a link button you can pass along the values from your gridview to the next form via querystring or as session variables.

Comment: How would you get the gridview values? The code above didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For editing you could use Edit Functionality of Gridview. If your requirement is to redirect to page with all detail (as coded by you) then don't loop through gridview but fetch only the particular row from which linkbutton is clicked:

```
 protected void lnkEditUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           LinkButton linkEdit =  (LinkButton)sender; // Point the particular row LinkButton clicked
           GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)linkEdit.NameingContainer;// Fetch the Row
           Employee newe = new Employee();
           newe.ID = int.Parse((gvEmployee.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1]).Text);
           newe.Name = (gvEmployee.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2]).Text;
           newe.Salary = (gvEmployee.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[3]).Text;
           Session["Update"] = newe;
           Response.Redirect("~/EditUpdateEmployee.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: is it link.Edit NamingConainer? because NameingContainer didn't work. Also I am getting a error for int.Parse(((BoundField)row.FindControl("txtID")).Text);. It says cannot convert type System.Web.UI.Control to System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField

Comment: Could I have a look on your Gridview codeing(aspx) how you created all Field?

Answer (score 0):

Use command argument of grid view property in button

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Column Name") %>' //this is for aspx
```

then in code behind call it

```
Response.write(e.commandargyment)//this is for aspx.cs
```

for more details watch this tutorial [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uhsVogOGYU&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo&index=99)

after that use query  string hope this help you.